# Finding triples that satisfy given constraints in $O (n \log n) $ time

Tags: algorithms

> Given a string comprised solely of the characters $\text{a, b, c}$ we want to know the number of different $(i, j, k)$ triples such that $0 \leq i,j, k < n \text{ (here n denotes the length of the string)}$ satisfying the following two conditios :
>
> $\bullet \text{ }s[i] = "a", s[j] ="b" \text{ and } s[k] = "c"$
>
> $\bullet \text{ } (j + 1)^2 = (i+1)(k + 1) $
>
> We consider such two tuples, $(i, j, k)$ and $(x, y, z)$ to be different only of $i \neq x$ or $j \neq y$ or $k \neq z$.
>
> Example case and solution :
>   The string $"ccaccbbbaccccca"$ with $n = 15$.
>   There are two triplets that satisfy the given constraints, namely $(2, 5, 11)$ and $(8, 5, 3)$.
>
> The second solution shows that $i$ is not necessarily less than $k$.

---

I know this is a programming question, but I'm more inclined to look for a mathematical approach that I currently seem to be missing. Since $n$ could be as large as $5 \cdot 10^5$ brute force is not feasible.

I've attempted coming by the solution by noticing that in order for $\sqrt{(i + 1)(k + 1) } = (j +1 ) \in \mathbb{N}$, $k +1$ should be of the form $(i + 1) \cdot \alpha^2$ or of the form $\frac{\alpha^2}{i + 1}$.

Hence, we would have to iterate and test in order to find the $
\alpha$ values that would satisfy our conditions. Later on, I found out by inspecting the process that the latter form covers all the solutions, multiple times, so I would only need to look for answers by using the second form.

This still led to a temporal complexity of $O(\sqrt{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k})$.

---

I've been at this for too many hours and I have no idea how to proceed. How would you solve this?
I'm guessing $O(n)$ isn't possible but $O(n \log n)$ should probably do the trick.

Comment: Interesting exercise.  Can you credit the source of this problem?  Where did you encounter this?

Answer (score 3):

Let us shift all of your indices by $1$. The condition on the indices then becomes $j^2 = ik$. The number of factorizations of $j^2$ into $i \cdot k$ is at most $d(j)^2$, where $d(j)$ is the number of divisors of $j$.  Therefore the total number of potential triples $(i,j,k)$ is at most
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n d(j)^2 = O(n\log^3 n).
$$
(For the estimate, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160079/second-moment-for-the-number-of-divisors-function) on Mathoverflow.) Note that the actual number of triples can also be bounded by $\sum_{j=1}^n d(j^2)$, which could be smaller (and it could be yet smaller even than this sum).

This means, at the very least, that if you know $n$ in advance, then you can make a list of $\tilde{O}(n)$ triples, and solve the problem in time $\tilde{O}(n)$. Using a sieve of Eratosthenes, you can likely also calculate the triples in $\tilde{O}(n)$; it might be worthwhile to store all primes at most $500,000$ ahead of time.